# merge xts objects with suffixes dynamically

Tags: r, xts, zoo

The task is to dynamically merge multiple `xts` objects into one big blob with suffixes, where suffixes are essentially the column names for the xts objects.

**Sample Data:**

```
library(xts)
a <- data.frame(alpha=1:10, beta=2:11)
xts1 <- xts(x=a, order.by=Sys.Date() - 1:10)
b <- data.frame(alpha=3:12, beta=4:13)
xts2 <- xts(x=b, order.by=Sys.Date() - 1:10)
c <- data.frame(alpha=5:14, beta=6:15)
xts3 <- xts(x=c, order.by=Sys.Date() - 1:10)
```

**Static way of merging:**

```
$> merge.zoo(xts1, xts2, xts3, suffixes=c("A", "B", "C"))
# output
           alpha.A beta.A alpha.B beta.B alpha.C beta.C
2022-03-11      10     11      12     13      14     15
2022-03-12       9     10      11     12      13     14
2022-03-13       8      9      10     11      12     13
2022-03-14       7      8       9     10      11     12
2022-03-15       6      7       8      9      10     11
2022-03-16       5      6       7      8       9     10
2022-03-17       4      5       6      7       8      9
2022-03-18       3      4       5      6       7      8
2022-03-19       2      3       4      5       6      7
2022-03-20       1      2       3      4       5      6
```

I might have more than 3 xts objets and 3 is just an arbitrary demonstration.

I've tried `do.call` but my `do.call` attempt failed with/out suffixes because I can't wrap up the 3 xts objects into a data structure that's accepted by do.call as a list (in R's language it should be a vector of 3 items).

**`do.call` Demo:**

```
# do.call with xts objects as separate args and suffixes, works
do.call(merge.zoo, list(xts1, xts2, xts3, suffixes=c("A", "B", "C")))

# do.call with xts objects wrapped up as list and suffixes, failed

# because R takes each element of list as vector and essentially a list of xts objects is a list of 3 lists, each of which has a xts object.

xts.list <- list(xts1, xts2, xts3)

# check data type
class(xts.list[[1]]) # output: xts,zoo
class(xts.list[1]) # output: list

# do.call failed attempt
do.call(merge.zoo, list(xts.list, suffixes=c("A", "B", "C")))
# Error Message
Error in zoo(structure(x, dim = dim(x)), index(x), ...) : 
“x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
```

In other words, if I can unpack the list into dynamic number of arguments, I'd be able to get this idea to work; however I can't seem to find a way to either unpack arguments in R or some other solutions.

*Disclaimer: The ultimate problem I am trying to solve is to be able to plot the time series data in the multi-panel view eventually; `ggplot` does not work with most of the packages I am using on a daily basis.*

*Disclaimer 2: `merge.xts` ignores suffixes (a bug), `merge.zoo` is the working alternative. For more information take a look [here](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/38)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can pass everything in a `list` i.e.

```
library(zoo)
c(xts.list, list(suffixes=c("A", "B", "C")))
```

Now, use the `merge` in `do.call`

```
do.call(merge.zoo, c(xts.list, list(suffixes=c("A", "B", "C"))))
```

-output

```
            alpha.A beta.A alpha.B beta.B alpha.C beta.C
2022-03-11      10     11      12     13      14     15
2022-03-12       9     10      11     12      13     14
2022-03-13       8      9      10     11      12     13
2022-03-14       7      8       9     10      11     12
2022-03-15       6      7       8      9      10     11
2022-03-16       5      6       7      8       9     10
2022-03-17       4      5       6      7       8      9
2022-03-18       3      4       5      6       7      8
2022-03-19       2      3       4      5       6      7
2022-03-20       1      2       3      4       5      6
```

Note that the first argument to `merge` is variadic component (`...` - which can take one or more xts data, where as all the other components are named and that is the reason we are creating the `list` with `names` only for those components i.e. suffixes.  According to `?merge`

> merge(...,
> all = TRUE,
> fill = NA,
> suffixes = NULL,
> join = "outer",
> retside = TRUE,
> retclass = "xts",
> tzone = NULL,
> drop=NULL,
> check.names=NULL)

Thus, when we want to append a `list` i.e. `xts.list` with another list element, wrap the second named vector in a `list` and then just `c`oncatenate.  It is similar to

```
> c(list(1), list(a = 1, b = 2))
[[1]]
[1] 1

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```

and not the following as this create a nested `list`

```
> list(list(1), list(a = 1, b = 2))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 1

[[2]]$b
[1] 2
```

Comment: I was stunned to be honest when I read this as I couldn't figure out why it was working (I was going to ask you right away); then I did a `help()` on `do.call` I found that `## if we already have a list (e.g., a data frame)
## we need c() to add further arguments` I need facepalm emoji. Thanks Akrun

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration on the `list` bit; I am still a little lost on that though: do we use `list` to help `merge.zoo` understand that anything within `list` is not part of the variadic argument?

Comment: @stucash the `list` is requirement only for do.call.  In your case, the first 3 list elements are unnamed and thus it will take those as the `...` part whereas the others (here it is only a single one i.. e `suffixes` is named list element).  Probably, the other arguments will be the default options from the function

Comment: @stucash With `do.call`, it is mentioned as `do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.` and `args - a list of arguments to the function call. The names attribute of args gives the argument names.`

Comment: what about `do.call(merge.zoo, c(xts.list, suffixes=c("A", "B", "C")))` ? I just tried this one, it worked though it did ignore `suffixes`; `do.call`'s help page has an example of calling extra arg without `list`, i.e., `do.call(paste c(tmp, sep=""))` here the `sep` was passed into without `list` but my example the list was a requirement..

Comment: @stucash the issue is that `c("A", "B", "C")` is a vector and when you concatenate it generates three elements in the `list` instead of a single one i.e. `$suffixes1
[1] "A"

$suffixes2
[1] "B"

$suffixes3
[1] "C"`.  We need only a single argument for `'suffixes` and that is the reasson we wrapped the vector in a `list`

Answer (score 2):

This is now (finally) fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/commit/62aa765db3be4c7bdd0078eff745c63f023c3076). Thanks for the nudge to get this fixed!

```r
library(xts)
idx <- Sys.Date() - 1:10
x1 <- xts(cbind(alpha = 1:10, beta = 2:11), idx)
x2 <- xts(cbind(alpha = 3:12, beta = 4:13), idx)
x3 <- xts(cbind(alpha = 5:14, beta = 6:15), idx)

suffixes <- LETTERS[1:3]

merge(x1, x2, x3, suffixes = suffixes)
##            alpha.A beta.A alpha.B beta.B alpha.C beta.C
## 2022-05-13      10     11      12     13      14     15
## 2022-05-14       9     10      11     12      13     14
## 2022-05-15       8      9      10     11      12     13
## 2022-05-16       7      8       9     10      11     12
## 2022-05-17       6      7       8      9      10     11
## 2022-05-18       5      6       7      8       9     10
## 2022-05-19       4      5       6      7       8      9
## 2022-05-20       3      4       5      6       7      8
## 2022-05-21       2      3       4      5       6      7
## 2022-05-22       1      2       3      4       5      6
```

Comment: I've just installed the develop version of `xts` (in my RStudio it is now showing `0.12.1.2`) but it seems the fix is not in yet. Did I miss something here? At the moment, the CRAN version of xts is still `0.12.1`

Comment: @stucash the CRAN version doesn't have the fix. Maybe I hadn't merged the fixed to master when you tried it. Can you try again? You can install via: `remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")`

Comment: @stucash have you had a chance to try this fix?

Comment: Hi Joshua sorry it took some time for me to revert back. I've tried it and it worked well and helped me refactor some of my code as well. I left a comment on the original [issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/38) page as well. Thank you for acting quickly.

Comment: Great to hear it's fixed for you!